# Efficient way to get top count of an option in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this,

```
[
  {
    user: 'A',
    answers: [
      {
        id: 1,
        score: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        score: 1,
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    user: 'B',
    answers: [
    ...
```

where I have 200 users, each user answers a set of 40 questions, each question has an id and a score.

What I'm trying to do is add up each question's score. So that I can figure out which question has the highest score, which has the lowest. Aka, top question and bottom question.

What would be the best way to do this?

The current way I am doing feels a little long-winded.

```
const allAns = []

myList.forEach( user => allAns.push( ...user.answers ) )

const questionsScored = allAns.reduce( ( obj, cur ) => {
  !obj[ cur.id ] ? obj[ cur.id ] = cur.score : obj[ cur.id ] += cur.score
  return obj
}, {} )

const sortingList = []
for ( const qn in questionsScored ) {
  sortingList.push( [ qn, questionsScored[ qn ] ] )
}
sortingList.sort( ( a, b ) => b[ 1 ] - a[ 1 ] )

console.log( sortingList[ 0 ], sortingList[ sortingList.length - 1 ] )
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Post it here?

Comment: Updated post with what I'm using at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking all the steps necessary so if it's working it's fine though you could replace some of your `forEach()` loops with available methods:

with [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
const allAns = myList.flatMap(({answers})=>answers);
```

and using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
const sortingList = Object.entries(questionsScored);
```

```js
const
  input = [{ user: 'A', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 3, }, { id: 2, score: 1, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] }, { user: 'B', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 2, }, { id: 2, score: 1, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] },],

  allAns = input.flatMap(({ answers }) => answers),

  questionsScored = allAns.reduce((obj, cur) => {
    !obj[cur.id] ? obj[cur.id] = cur.score : obj[cur.id] += cur.score
    return obj
  }, {}),

  sortingList = Object.entries(questionsScored).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

console.log({ max: sortingList[0], min: sortingList[sortingList.length - 1] })
```

Or combined into a single chained call, but it's not necessarily better.

```js
const
  input = [{ user: 'A', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 3, }, { id: 2, score: 1, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] }, { user: 'B', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 2, }, { id: 2, score: 1, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] },],

  sortingList = Object
    .entries(
      input
        .flatMap(({ answers }) => answers)
        .reduce((obj, cur) => {
          !obj[cur.id] ? obj[cur.id] = cur.score : obj[cur.id] += cur.score
          return obj
        }, {})
    )
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

console.log({ max: sortingList[0], min: sortingList[sortingList.length - 1] })
```

If you would like to avoid the `sort()` call you can instead collect the low and high counts using a `forEach()` after the initial `reduce()`

```js
const
  input = [{ user: 'A', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 3, }, { id: 2, score: 1, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] }, { user: 'B', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 2, }, { id: 2, score: 1, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] },],

  lowScore = { count: Infinity },
  highScore = { count: -Infinity };

Object
  .entries(
    input
      .flatMap(({ answers }) => answers)
      .reduce((obj, cur) => {
        !obj[cur.id] ? obj[cur.id] = cur.score : obj[cur.id] += cur.score
        return obj
      }, {})
  )
  .forEach(([id, count]) => {
    // update low count
    if (count < lowScore.count) {
      lowScore.count = count;
      lowScore.id = id;
    }
    // update high count
    if (count > highScore.count) {
      highScore.count = count;
      highScore.id = id;
    }
  });

console.log({ lowScore, highScore })
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// sample data
let data = [{
        user: 'A',
        answers: [{
                id: 1,
                score: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                score: 2,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                score: 3,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                score: 4,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        user: 'B',
        answers: [{
                id: 1,
                score: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                score: 2,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                score: 3,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                score: 4,
            },
        ]
    },
]


let scoreSum = []; //scoreSum to store  total score of each question
let initialValue = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let sum = data.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator + currentValue.answers[i].score;
    }, initialValue)

    scoreSum.push(sum);
}

let highestScore = Math.max(...scoreSum);
let lowestScore = Math.min(...scoreSum);
// increasing index by 1 to match with question numbers
let highestScoreIndex = scoreSum.indexOf(highestScore) + 1;
let lowestScoreIndex = scoreSum.indexOf(lowestScore) + 1;


// Array.prototype.getDuplicates  returns an object where the keys are the duplicate entries 
// and the values are an array with their indices.
Array.prototype.getDuplicates = function () {
    var duplicates = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (duplicates.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
            duplicates[this[i]].push(i);
        } else if (this.lastIndexOf(this[i]) !== i) {
            duplicates[this[i]] = [i];
        }
    }

    return duplicates;
};


let sameScore = scoreSum.getDuplicates();

// checking if highest score has duplicates
// and if so then updaing highest score index
//with highest score indices
if (sameScore.hasOwnProperty(highestScore)) {
    highestScoreIndex = sameScore[highestScore].map((a) => a + 1);
}
// checking if lowest score has duplicates
// and if so then updaing lowest score index
//with lowest score indices
if (sameScore.hasOwnProperty(lowestScore)) {
    lowestScoreIndex = sameScore[lowestScore].map((a) => a + 1);
}


console.log(`Top question no(s): ${highestScoreIndex}  highest score:${highestScore}`);
console.log(`bottom question no(s): ${lowestScoreIndex}  lowest score:${lowestScore}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I only loop once through each `answer` in `.answers` for each `user` using nested `reduce`.

The `input` array got three users with each three answers.

```js
let input = [{ user: 'A', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 2, }, { id: 2, score: 1, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] }, { user: 'B', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 2, }, { id: 2, score: 4, }, { id: 3, score: 0, }] }, { user: 'c', answers: [{ id: 1, score: 0, }, { id: 2, score: 3, }, { id: 3, score:5, }] }]

function showBestAndWorstFrom(input) {
  let highestScore = {'id': 0, 'score': -Infinity};
  let lowestScore =  {'id': 0, 'score': Infinity};
  let currentScore = 0;
  let id = 0;
  const LAST_USER = input.length - 1;

  let answers = input.reduce((combinedObj, user, userIndex) => {
    return user.answers.reduce((_answerObj, _answer) => {
      id = _answer.id
      currentScore = (_answerObj[id] || 0) + _answer.score;
      _answerObj[id] = currentScore;
      
      if (userIndex == LAST_USER) {
        highestScore = (highestScore.score < currentScore) ? {'id': id, 'score': currentScore } : highestScore;     
        lowestScore  = (lowestScore.score  > currentScore) ? {'id': id, 'score': currentScore } : lowestScore;
      }
    
      return _answerObj;
    }, combinedObj);
  }, {});
  
  // console.log(answers); // { "1": 4, "2": 8, "3": 5 }
  
  return {highestScore, lowestScore};
}

console.log(showBestAndWorstFrom(input))
```